# How to handle bad title of original question?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicates

I wanted to install Netbeans 8.1 and I searched the internet and everybody was talking about 8.0. So I though to ask: [How to install netbeans v8.1 in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/753517/how-to-install-netbeans-v8-1-in-ubuntu-14-04)

I was *lucky* and the user who had answered the duplicate was online and prompted me to it. Should I mark my own question as a duplicate?

Back in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716255/why-does-this-program-print-forked-4-times), we had a similar issue and a merging was finally done.

I just *feel* that the next user will fail to find the answer immediately. The other question has a bad title.

Comment: I went ahead an edited that post. It should be much more searchable now.

Comment: Thank you very much @muru, since a lot happened on my side and could not focus on that. :)

Comment: This is why titles and tags are important.

Comment: Also, now its a dupe people that find your question will find that question

Comment: I marked that as a dupe @Wilf, thinking what you said. Merging would maybe be the ideal (as in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716255/why-does-this-program-print-forked-4-times/26716300#26716300), but it's requires time, so I think it's a good trade-off.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To generalize:

***If the question has a bad title, edit it***

if a question's title is an obstacle to find the real content of it, I edit it into a more appropriate title. You can think of the following situations:

- A question is more specific then needed, e.g.:

  *"How do I copy a file from command line in 14.04"*

  Copying files from cli is not Ubuntu version -specific.
- A question's title is focussing on the wrong subject due to a lack of understanding, e.g.:

  *"How can I run this program on reboot"*

  while OP obviously means *log in*

  And:

  "*How can I set the `DISPLAY` variable when changing wallpaper from `cron`*"

  while the missing variable is a different one

In cases like this, many times I edit the question's title to make it more appropriate, corresponding to the real issue inside the question. As specific as necessary, but as generalized as the question allows.

No need to explain that the same goes for tags.